# Can't remove a file which created by `tempfile.mkstemp()` on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, file-io, temporary-files

Here's my example code:

```
import os
from tempfile import mkstemp

fname = mkstemp(suffix='.txt', text=True)[1]
os.remove(fname)
```

When I run it on my Linux, it works fine. But when I run it on my Windows XP using Python 3.4.4, it raised the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.remove(fname)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\DOCUME~1\\IEUser\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\tmp3qv6ppcf.txt'
```

However, when I use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` to create a temp file and close it, it removed automatically.

Why Windows can't remove files created by `mkstemp`? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try closing it first?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Huh? Where did I open it? Isn't `mkstemp()` just create the file? There's no `open()` in my code and `fname` is a string object.

Comment: Note that mkstemp() returns a **tuple** with an open file handle. Until you don't close that handle the file is in use (...by another process: your own one). It works on Windows because of how os.remove() works (_On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised; on Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage allocated to the file is not made available until the original file is no longer in use_).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Ah, I totally misunderstood the document...

Comment: With `NamedTemporaryFile`, Python is using WinAPI `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, which requires `DELETE` access and the file is opened with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` sharing. That means you can call `os.remove` on it without getting a sharing violation, but note that the file isn't actually removed until the last kernel reference or handle is closed. The delete-on-close flag causes the file-system to mark the file to be unlinked, but this doesn't happen until the last reference is closed. An existing handle can call `SetFileInformationByHandle` to undo the delete disposition.

Comment: @eryksun: Ah, yeah. Just misunderstood the document about what does the first element in that tuple do. Didn't notice that it's a handle before.

Comment: `mkstemp` doesn't use `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` (via the CRT `O_TEMPORARY` flag), so it doesn't open the file with `DELETE` access or `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` sharing. When you try to call `os.remove` on it, that calls WinAPI `DeleteFile`, which tries to open with `DELETE` access to set the delete disposition, which fails because you have the file open without delete sharing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp):

> Creates a temporary file in the most secure manner possible. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> `mkstemp()` returns a tuple containing an OS-level handle to an open file (as would be returned by `os.open()`) and the absolute pathname of that file, in that order.

```
fd, fname = mkstemp(suffix='.txt', text=True)
os.close(fd)
os.remove(fname)
```